# Prevent welcome screen from showing up on Raspberry Pi

Tags: front-end

I am using Mathematica 12.3.1 on Raspberry Pi. Every time it starts, what I called "welcome screen" appears alongside new document window. For me this is an annoyance.

[image]

Can we disable this screen?

Comment: Not sure about the Rpi specifically, but it is under Edit->Preferences: goto the Interface tab. There is a "Show at Startup" item.

Comment: I have never been able to get rid of the mathematica welcome screen on the Raspberry. If it is possible it is as way more difficult than with the mathematica under windows. It's a pity : Because of this I gave up to make a mathematica juke-box on raspberry. (it was a few years ago, on a raspberry 2)

Comment: ...It is all the more a pity that the touchscreen of the raspberry works fine with mathematica.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not a splash screen or a welcome screen.  It's the Mathematica Navigator notebook window.  There is a way to prevent it from opening and a programmatic way to close it.

From the notebook menu, use the Format -> Options Inspector.  Then change the Selection to Global Preferences and search for AutoOpenNotebooks.  After you futz with the window size and the column widths, this is what it should look like:

[image]

Remove the AutoOpenNotebooks option by clicking the icon that looks like 3 dots in in a square on the same line as the option, to the far right.  That will open a Properties dialog.  Click Remove, click Ok.  Now it should look like this

[image]

Close the Options Inspector, and Bob's your uncle.

Here's a command that will close the Navigator window,

```
If[MemberQ[Keys[NotebookInformation[#]], "FileName"] && 
     MemberQ[FileNames[
       "MathematicaNavigator.nb", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
      NotebookFileName[#]],
    NotebookClose[#]] &   /@ Notebooks[];
```

The command looks at all the notebooks.  It first only wants the notebooks that have a file name, then it checks the file path before closing the notebook.  It might be useful when you can't or don't want to change the global setting, but don't want the distraction of that navigator notebook either.

**Edit:  Do it the quick way**

Using the Option Inspector is unnecessary.  Simply evaluate `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, AutoOpenNotebooks->{}]` in the front end and then exit MMA completely.  The next time MMA starts, the Navigator window will not appear.