# How to customize the startup page for Mathematica

Tags: notebooks, customization, documentation, kernel-startup

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the startup page for Mathematica: [image: startup page for Mathematica].
I am aware that if this is possible it will involve modifying the program files for Mathematica in the back end. Where can I find the startup page's notebook object? I searched wolfram.com for welcome page and welcome screen and was not able to find a documentation center page on the location of the start page's notebook address.
For example, I would like to include a link to Wolfram University as it boots up.
I have found the location of the file but don't know how to edit the actual file as a notebook object.
The file location can be found as follows:

```
FileNames["MathematicaNavigator.nb", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]
```

[image]

I have looked for the notebook that opens automatically at startup in the Options Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+O).
[image]
My goal is to edit the startup page as a notebook object programmatically.
[A helpful question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258076/prevent-welcome-screen-from-showing-up-on-raspberry-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1) that relates to the topic of the startup page.

Comment: "I realize that the startup page is not a notebook" The welcome screen is in fact a notebook. You can show it using Help -> Welcome Screen, then use `Notebooks[]` to get a handle to it.

Comment: Where is the file for the startup notebook located?

Comment: I don't know. There may not be a separate file for it. I searched and could not find it. These are normally in SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources.

Comment: It is called "MathematicaNavigator.nb". Try `FileNames["MathematicaNavigator.nb", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]`.

Comment: How do I edit the file? Every time I click on it I am unable to edit it.

Comment: Look at this recent [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258076/prevent-welcome-screen-from-showing-up-on-raspberry-pi). Perhaps you can find some pointers.